# Create pattern and save it to 24-bit RGB PNG file

Tags: imagemagick, png

How can I create PNG file with ImageMagick pattern (e. g. input file `pattern:gray50`) and save it to 24-bit RGB PNG file using ImageMagick commandline?

This produces 8-bit PNG file:

```
convert -size 64x64 pattern:gray50 output.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you can force the output PNG to 24-bits by prefacing the output with PNG24.  Try

```
convert -size 64x64 pattern:gray50 PNG24:output.png
```